# why my external harddrive fails after connecting it to windows

Tags: 14.04, partitioning, hard-drive

I bought an external harddrive. 
I format it with typing `Disk` and the `Format` and then `Quick`  and `FAT`
I copied many documents there which was working just fine

Then I connected it to a windows and did not show up.
Then I connect it again to Ubuntu and it says

```
Disk is OK, 5 attributes are failing
```

what is the problem?
how can I fix it? those documents are very important for me

Thanks

Comment: first backup the data, in case the drive is really failing. how big is the drive? FAT has a size limit. formatting ntfs is preferable for a windows partition.

Comment: @ravery  how to back it up when I cannot mount it? The harddrive is 8TB but it only shows 2TB of usage . what I need now is only to be able to get the data out of it and then I will be fine

Comment: @ ravery do you know how I can get the data out?

Comment: it won't mount in ubuntu? clonezilla will do a raw sector by sector clone of a drive to a new drive.

Comment: @ravery no it does not mount. what is clonezilla?

Comment: clonezilla is a drive clone/imaging program.  similar to norton ghost. http://clonezilla.org/

Comment: @ravery can you please guide me how to do that? it is because the info are very important for me and I dont want to lose them by any mistake

Comment: download the image. burn it to disk. boot the cd.

Comment: @ I downloaded the iso using windows7 then I burned it on a DVD and I put the DVD in the UBUNTU machine. when I click on the iso file. it open a folder with many foders in it like boot, EFI etc etc

Comment: you have to burn the image to disk not copy the file.

Comment: @ravery  I burn the file 3 times iso as image . when it mount , it does not have any executable file. it has a folder with several folders in it

Comment: it is a boot CD. boot from it. there are executable files on it. if youare burning theimage not copying the file to disk. NOTE: secure boot has to be off

Comment: @ravery should I burn it on windows or linux?

Comment: it doesn't matter which system you use to burn the CD/DVD. since OS is on the disk. just make sure that you chose burn image to disk, not make a data CD/DVD if you did it correctly, you should see all those folders on the disk. restart your computer with the disk in the drive NOTE: secure boot must be turned off for the CD to boot.

Comment: @ravery  I did it and now my linux page is blue . what should I do now ?

Comment: boot up the CD. try backup to image first. if that doesn't worrk, you need to do a sector by sector clone to another drive

Comment: Try using something like exFAT, it’s supported on windows and supports larger disk and file sizes.

Answer (score 0):

Before you do anything else, please clarify and investigate this comment:

> The harddrive is 8TB but it only shows 2TB of usage

In many cases, disks over 2 TiB are problematic because of 32-bit pointer limits in MBR partition tables and in some disk drivers and even hardware (especially USB-to-disk interface hardware). Traditionally, disk sectors are 512 bytes in size, and 2^32 x 512 bytes works out to precisely 2 TiB. (Note: 1 TiB = 1024^4 bytes; 1 TB = 1000^4 bytes.) Thus, if a driver or hardware component has a 32-bit limit and if the disk is larger than 2 TiB, you can see some odd effects -- typically, the disk's size will appear to be some value under 2 TiB, because the size will "wrap around," much like an old car's odometer with too few digits to register a high-mileage value. Occasionally these limits appear in one OS (typically Windows) but not another, which can create real problems for inter-OS usage. Something similar can happen if you use a disk inside a computer (where the problem is less likely to manifest) and then try to access it using a USB adapter or external USB enclosure (many such devices impose a 32-bit limit).

Some external USB enclosures try to work around this limit by "translating" sector sizes -- they take groups of eight 512-byte sectors and convert them into individual 4096-byte sectors. This raises the 2 TiB limit to 16 TiB, but it means that moving the disk between the external enclosure and internal use (where no such translation occurs) is even more problematic, since most disk accesses and references are done by sector value, and those sector values are not consistent between the two interface types.

A less problematic explanation for the discrepancy you report is that the disk might use MBR, which has its own 32-bit limit. The newer GPT partitioning system raises that limit well beyond current needs by using 64-bit pointers. If the disk is partitioned with MBR and uses 512-byte sectors, it will top out at 2 TiB, even if it's an 8 TB model. This in and of itself should not cause data corruption, but of course you'll be able to use barely over 1/4 of its capacity. Switching from MBR to GPT is an easy solution in this case. My `gdisk` program (included standard in Ubuntu) can do this, but you'll need to either resize the partition or create a new one to use the additional capacity after the conversion. See [this page of the `gdisk` documentation](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/mbr2gpt.html) for information on how to do the conversion.

In any event, some additional information will help clarify this question:

- The output of `sudo parted /dev/sdb print` (changing `/dev/sdb` to the disk identifier) in Linux
- Clarification on the disk's claimed size
- Whether you bought the disk as an external disk or created an external disk yourself by placing an internal disk in an enclosure you bought separately
- Clarification on whether you've *always* used the disk as an external model or if you've used it both internally and via your enclosure
- Information on the type of interface the external enclosure uses (USB, FireWire, eSATA, etc.)